# Git branching / workflow model like "nvie gitflow" but without release branches

Tags: git, github, git-flow

Is there an official documented git workflow just like nvie's "Gitflow" workflow but without the release branches?

http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow

I guess I don't see the purpose of the release branches, why not just tag a release from master? (Maybe that's the same thing).

Comment: Release branches are temporary, like feature branches. Once they have been merged into develop, the release is tagged and the branch is deleted.

Comment: @mipadi sorry that doesn't make sense, are you sure what you said is correct?

Comment: @mipadi after reading through das-g's answer twice I now understand what you are saying, thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The concept of releases in the nvie's branching model (and consequently in the `git-flow` tool) is related to the distinction between the branches `master` and `develop`. In both, nvie's model and GitHub's model, `master` is supposed to be 'fit for production'. But how can you ensure that?

> why not just tag a release from master?

## GitHub's branching model does just that ...

If there are few concurrent feature branches, you simply test (and review, as well as any other QA you want or need) your feature branches before you merge them into `master`. If significant changes have been merged into `master` (or if changes have — in violation of the branching model — been directly committed to `master`) since the respective feature branch was branched off, merge `master` into the feature branch *before* testing, so you're already testing an integrated state of your code.

For this, GitHub's branching model, as [mentioned by Chase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31885689/674064) works perfectly fine.

If releasing involves some code changes (e.g. bumping version numbers, summarizing changelogs), one can do this directly on `master` or on a dedicated branch. In any case, `master` serves here as **both**, integration and stable branch.

## ... but that's not enough for every project

If you apply GitHub's branching model in projects with many concurrent feature branches, and some of the latter not as short-lived as you might wish, it becomes likely that by the time you've tested and QAed your feature branch (with `master` merged into it), `master` has already changed by other merges, so you'd have to test all over. Also, with that much going on in the project, it might be difficult for you to know what all to test to ensure you didn't break any of the other (maybe just recently merged) features.

### nvie's `master` (stable) ↔ `develop` (integration) distinction

Thus, in busy projects, it makes sense to have an integration / stabilization branch, where all feature branches will be merged after respectively having been tested and QAed *individually*. This gives the chance to test and QA the feature implementations again in combination before deciding whether a given snapshot of this integration shall become a release and thereby declared 'fit for use'. Nvie's branching model calls this integration branch `develop`. `master` loses the integration role and just becomes the branch for the deemed-stable snapshots of `develop`.

But wait — "snapshots" — isn't that exactly what Git tags provide? Why the separate branch `master`, then? And again:

> why not just tag a release from <del>master</del>[develop]?

Only for convenience: Users (or operators, deployment attachés, ...) who do not care what exact version they are using, as long as it is a stable version (or who want the latest and greatest *stable* version) can just check out `master` (and pull `master` to update), without having to look what tags there are and without having to figure out your version numbering scheme.

### Release branches

> I always thought releases as being static clones, not dynamic branches.

They are. A release branch is **not** a finished release. It's a release-in-preparation. It's used to bump version numbers, and perform other code changes that you might not want to do on feature branches (e.g., because they obfuscate the actual implementation changes) but that are necessary for the finished software. (E.g. syncing translation files with the UI strings actually needed in the application.)

Release branches can be arbitrarily short-lived. Once you're confident with your release preparations, you merge the release branch to `develop` and `master`, additionally placing a tag **and then *delete* the release branch**.

**Do not use release branches for maintaining a version.** That's what hotfix and (in more recent versions of the `git-flow` tool) support branches are for.

Why not do all those releasing commits directly on `develop`? Well, if they take longer (or if they require cooperation and therefor need publishing of intermediate states), having them on a dedicated release branch allows you to have control over what makes it into the release and what doesn't, without having to block `develop` for further integration of features that become ready while you're busy releasing.

#### Release branches in `git flow`

Even if your releases require no additional steps, because you didn't put the version of your project into the repository's content and don't have to update the used versions of third-party dependencies, and don't postpone updating your translations, etc., it might be worth to use the `release` subcommands of `git flow`, because they help you not to forget important rules of nvie's branching model, by automating them:

- merge the release branch into both, `master` **and** `develop`
- tag the release consistently
- actually delete the release branch when done

If releasing doesn't require cooperation (or doesn't involve dedicated steps at all in your project), you can

```
git flow release start <version number>
git flow release finish <same version number>
```

without ever pushing the release branch before `finish` deletes it again (after merging and tagging, which is the effect you'd want).

To make the resulting release visible to the world, then

```
git push origin develop master <version you just released>
```

so that the merges on both branches and the new tag will be sent to `origin`.

If you *have* pushed the release branch (be it manually or with `git flow publish release <version number>`), instead use

```
git push origin :release/<version number> develop master <version number>
```

Comment: I've been trying to wrap my head around GitFlow for a while now and this break down of the branch purposes helped better than any documentation I've read so far.  Thank you.

Comment: 1) How would you QA/test on feature branch? Run tests after pull-request and commit bugfixes into that pull request? If so, how to determine versionCode/versionName for that test?

2)  How would you QA/test on develop branch? How to determine versionCode/versionName for that tests?

Answer (score 4):

There's a pretty good simplified version provided [here](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/) by Github.

[Here](http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/) is one with tagging that I send to all of our new employees.

Comment: upvoted, thanks, but no, the "Github workflow" is too simplistic. IMO it can't ever just be master branch and feature branches, it has to be master branch, develop branch, then feature branches, where the feature branches go into the develop branch first before develop goes into master. if you use continuous integration, you can't put feature branches directly into master, at least as far as I am concerned without further knowledge.

Comment: so I guess nvie's workflow is good, but just have to ignore the parts about release branches. I always thought releases as being static clones, not dynamic branches.

Comment: Yeah nvie's is basically what we use, but with tagging.

Comment: Chase, you using tagging or do not use tagging

Comment: We use tagging, and FWIW we are switching to a gitflow-like model. This atlassin article is great https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow . We used to do a feature branch workflow, and we are now branching off of Develop and merging release versions of develop into a tagged release on master.